# How to do a for loop with subtraction in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How do I write this for loop in CoffeeScript?

> for(i = cc.length - 2, i >= 0, i -= 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in [cc.length - 2..0] by -2
  ...
```

Compilation [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afor%20i%20in%20%5Bcc.length%20-%202..0%5D%20by%20-2%0A%20%20i). The `by` keyword isn't very well-known, but it's invaluable.

One caveat: You have to remember to do the range backward (`upper..0`). And you **cannot** iterate through an array backward with this approach:

```
for i in arr by -1  # infinite loop!
```

Comment: woa , i did not see that one , was looking for that for years , thanks.

Comment: I saw the 'by' keyword when searching earlier.. but never thought to do a negative!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
i = cc.length-2
while  i>=0
  #code
  i-=2
```

Comment: +1 I find this easier to read than the negative `by`-loop with the inverted range.